# When I resize a cluster size 1000 to 0, GKE node remains about 30 minutes on kubectl get node result

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Please let me a Question.
I am using Locust Cluster built on GKE 1000 node (replica sets: 6400).
Locust Cluster works fine, but there are some problems in stopping this environment.
When I tried to stop by the following command, I faced the problem that the node in a ready state remained on `kubectl get node` for more than 30 minutes. I think this is a problem in that I can't restart the cluster readily.

> gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize gke-locust-xxxx --zone asia-east1-a --size 0

Because of GKE, I can not see what is happening on the master node. Are there any possible reasons? Or is it the specification of kubernetes performance that it takes this time.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I faced the problem that the node in a ready state remained on
>   kubectl get node for more than 30 minutes.

Did you watch the number of VMs in your managed instance group over that 30 minute period? How long did it take for all of them to disappear? If you delete a VM from a GKE cluster, it should be removed from `kubectl get nodes` within a couple of minutes, so it seems that the slowness is likely from removing the VMs themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  As far as I watch, it seems that the GKE node VM has been deleted on the GCE console in a few minutes. And the number of VMs in your managed instance group had also been counted as 0 in a few minutes.  However, the list of nodes displayed by `kubectl get nodes` has just been deleted in about 30 minutes. So I couldn't think that the slowness is likely from removing the VMs themselves.

Comment: That is unexpected. Is this reproducible or did it only happen once?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this behavior many times.  The reproduction procedure is as I posted first. And I use kuberntes v1.5.4(Master version1.5.4 ,Minion version1.5.4). Any idea?

Comment: If you need it I can also add information of instance-group and instance-template-settings. Thank you.

Comment: [sorry for the delayed response]: Did you delete the replica sets prior to scaling the number of nodes down to zero? I believe that when the master notices that a node is gone it will delete any pods running on the nodes. If the number of nodes is changing rapidly, this could cause a lot of churn in terms of rescheduling pods, plus pods often have a grace period before they can be deleted, either of which could lead to long delays in the nodes actually disappearing (they should be marked as "NotReady" pretty quickly though). Can you try deleting all of your workloads and then scaling down?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, And sorry for the delayed response.
This is the different situation from the node-delete situation, recently I faced the problem that GKE master's latency got worse if I started and stop 1900 nodes.
According to the response of the support case, I found out the following situation. "GKE master reinforcement was not made in time so CPU resources were exhausted and latency worsened".

Comment: I think that the problem thrown by this question was the same cause. I have heard about improvement plan of GKE master, but I will not write it here. I would like to think that GKE master's resource exhaustion can occur when rapidly increasing the node. So I will not do that.